# cannot use "Include" in Linqpad

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I am connecting to an Oracle DB and want to do a simple query using `Include`:

[image]

but I am getting this error:

```
CS1061 'ISessionTable<People>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'ISessionTable<People>' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)
```

I have already added these References:

```
System.Data.Entity.dll
System.Data.Linq.dll
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I did:
First off, add `EntityFramework.dll` in you Additional References (Press F4!). If you can't find it, download it from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework)

Then switch to "C# Statement(s)" and add `using System.Data.Entity;` and it should work. It seems as an alternative you also can add `System.Data.Entity` in "Additional Namespace Imports".

Comment: I tried this, and I can still see it running multiple queries in the SQL view

Answer (score 0):

Go to Query Properties and in '`Additional Namespaces`', include `System.Data.Objects`

The Include method is not supported with LINQ to SQL.

See [this](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/205/include-extension-method-is-not-found).

Comment: _Also, I take it that you're connecting to a custom Entity Framework context? The Include method is not supported with LINQ to SQL._  [their](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/205/include-extension-method-is-not-found)